# SQL php query past, present, not future

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a query that does the following: populates the site with today's 14 most current articles. If there aren't any for today, populate a previous day's articles.

But if future dates are in the database, the following SQL query breaks and 
does not populate the page. Any advice on writing this better?

```
// Select the current date's content or the previous date's if the current  date's content is unavailable
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM daily WHERE post_date = (SELECT MAX(post_date) from daily) and post_date < NOW() ORDER BY list_order ASC LIMIT 14";
```

Comment: I suggest you to create a new column created having data type date then it should be better to handle this situation

Comment: post_date is data type date

Comment: `SELECT * FROM daily WHERE post_date  =< NOW() ORDER BY post_date desc LIMIT 14`

Comment: in your query post_date<NOW() then it can not retrive result because the condition will false.

Comment: You can use post_date<=NOW()

Comment: Adding the <= is a good tip. But the query still breaks (returns nothing) when the database houses a a future date stored in post_date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT post_date, ....
FROM daily
WHERE post_date = (
    -- the last date, not future
    SELECT MAX(post_date)
    FROM daily
    WHERE (post_date <= DATE(NOW()))
)
ORDER BY list_order ASC
LIMIT 14
```

My advice : `SELECT *` is a bad practice because it prevents from searching the column's name in the code, and it obscures the code because whe don't know what column is useful.

Comment: I have to use * at the moment because the over all structure (probably not the best... but currently working). With that said, your solution works perfectly. Thank you for the knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

if post_date is date type then

```
"SELECT * FROM daily ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 14"
```

It populates the site with today's 14 most current articles. If there aren't any  populate a previous day's articles.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for your solution.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM daily WHERE post_date = (SELECT MAX(post_date) from daily WHERE post_date < NOW()) ORDER BY list_order ASC LIMIT 14";
```